# Powershell error when trying to use Set-ItemProperty with DefaultAppPool

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to do what is suggested in the answer here: [How do I set the .NET Framework Version when using New-WebAppPool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229082/powershell-how-do-i-set-the-net-framework-version-when-using-new-webapppool)

and using the command:

```
Set-ItemProperty C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\DefaultAppPool managedRuntimeVersion v4.0
```

I get this error however

> Set-ItemProperty : Property System.String managedRuntimeVersion=v4.0
>   does not exist. At line:1 char:17 + Set-ItemProperty <<<< 
>   C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\DefaultAppPool    managedRuntimeVersion v4.0
>   + CategoryInfo: ReadError: (System.String managedRuntimeVersion=v4.0:PSNoteProperty) [IOException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId
>   :SetPropertyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand

I think that I loaded the Web Administration module correctly (right clicked on the taskbar icon and selected "Import System Modules" and then tried the commands in that shell) and I've also tried using the command and explicitly stating the parameters and it still occurs. Same problem happens with other properties like AutoStart.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C:\` is the from the file system provider. Keith's answer in the SO question you linked is using the IIS provider `IIS:\`.

```
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\<pool_name> managedRuntimeVersion v4.0
```

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you for replying, I responded to manojlds above about this, if you could take a look at it that'd be great!

Comment: @Marzipan Did you add the IIS snapin first? `add-pssnapin WebAdministration`

Comment: I can't use add-pssnapin for some reason, but it works when I do Import-Module. Based on another stack overflow post I'm guessing it's because of my version of IIS?

I can do cd IIS:\ and stuff now though! thanks for the help

Comment: @Marzipan Do you have IIS 7 or 7.5?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 uses 7.5 I think

Comment: @Marzipan I think `Add-Snapin` is for IIS 7. R2 does 7.5. I think that's why you need to use import-module because snapins are considered legacy now.

Answer (score 1):

`C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\DefaultAppPool` - you are pointing to the filesystem.

Use the IIS provider to point to the App Pool.

It will be something like `IIS:\AppPools\Name`

Comment: I actually tried this originally and it said "Cannot find drive. A drive with the name "IIS" does not exist."

I was originally looking at this site http://www.jonoble.com/blog/2011/10/7/finding-iis-application-pool-states-with-powershell.html and they say that you should be able to navigate to it using cd but that doesn't work for me either. So I thought perhaps mine was somewhere else and I found that AppPools folder in inetpub/temp

Comment: When I ran into the  "Cannot find drive. A drive with the name "IIS" does not exist." error, I simply needed to add this line at the beginning of my script: import-module webadministration